# Adding conditional leading or trailing zeros

Tags: r, conditional-statements, trailing, leading-zero

I need help conditionally adding leading or trailing zeros.

I have a dataframe with one column containing icd9 diagnoses. as a vector, the column looks like:

```
"33.27" "38.45" "9.25" "4.15" "38.45" "39.9" "84.1" "41.5" "50.3"
```

I need all the values to have the length of 5, including the period in the middle (not counting ""). If the value has one digit before the period, it need to have a leading zero. If value has one digit after the period, it need to have zero at the end. So the result should look like this:

```
"33.27" "38.45" "09.25" "04.15" "38.45" "39.90" "84.10" "41.50" "50.30"
```

Here is the vector for R:

```
icd9 <- c("33.27", "38.45", "9.25", "4.15", "38.45", "39.9", "84.1", "41.5", "50.3" )
```

Comment: Why do you need that?  If for exporting to some tool that requires fixed-width records, spaces are the same as zeros, and easily achieved with `fwrite` .  If for setting up a tablular display, use table command arguments to set the alignment.

Answer (score 10):

This does it in one line

`formatC(as.numeric(icd9),width=5,format='f',digits=2,flag='0')`

Comment: Yep, that's the better way I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

ICD-9 codes have some formatting quirks which can lead to misinterpretation with simple string processing. The [icd](https://cran.r-project.org/package=icd) package on CRAN takes care of all the corner cases when doing ICD processing, and has been battle-tested over about six years of use by many R users.

Answer (score 0):

Using this function called change that accepts the argument of the max number of characters, i think it can help

```
 change<-function(x, n=max(nchar(x))) gsub(" ", "0", formatC(x, width=n))
    icd92<-gsub(" ","",paste(change(icd9,5)))
```

Comment: `icd92[6]` gives `"039.9"` - there looks to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sprintf` after converting the vector into numeric.

```
sprintf("%05.2f", as.numeric(icd9))
[1] "33.27" "38.45" "09.25" "04.15" "38.45" "39.90" "84.10" "41.50" "50.30"
```

*Notes*

- The examples in `?sprint` to get work out the proper format.
- There is some risk of introducing errors due to numerical precision here, though it works well in the example.